# Python MysqlClient (MYSQLDB) cant connect to a remote server

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using python version 2.7.15 and i also did pip2.7 install --upgrade mysqlclient

However, I am to connect to all remote databases which are version 5.6 or 5.7 but I cant connect to a remote mysql db 5.1

Same response happens when I try to connect from my local mysqlclient (without python)

Is there a correlation between the two when python client operates?

The error is :

```
       /local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init_
       super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
      _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2027, 'Malformed packet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `Mysqlclient` version

`pip install --upgrade mysqlclient`

I had have the same question , but solved it  this  way